# Android: Java SimpleDateFormat: Why February is March?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I can't resolve this question.

I wrote this code:

```
public static String getMonthName(int year, int month, int day){
    Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM",locale);
    Date date = new Date();
    date.setDate(day);
    date.setMonth(month);
    date.setYear(year);
    return sdf.format(date);
}
```

It works very well but when month = 1 (that is February), month name is March and not February! Why?

This code works very well for all other days and months...

There is another way to get translated month name?

Please help me....

Comment: what is the relevance of the day and year in the getting of the month name ?

Comment: also, can you post several outputs ? (month = 0, 1, 5, 10 for instance?)

Comment: increment month by one before setting it in to date object.

Comment: it works fine with me 0=January  , 1= February and 2= March

Comment: Many thanks I resolved with your help  njzk2 .
Today is 29 and February has 28 days so when the process pass 29 the result is march and not February...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on how you call your function (eg using current day as the 29 of Feb which doesn't exist in 2013), you may make the month being incremented automatically.

I'd suggest the use of this function which avoids the problem :

```
public static String getMonthName(int month){
    Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM",locale);
    Date date = new Date();
    date.setDate(1);
    date.setMonth(month);
    date.setYear(2012);
    return sdf.format(date);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Feb in 2021 is also 28 which I spent the whole day search for a solution. This is worked pretty fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the months start from zero index, So you should use this logic

```
if(day >0)
{
day =day -1;
}
```